# in __getitem__ return self.models[model_name] KeyError: 'mham_app.mham_app' - - -

Tags: odoo

try to extend timesheet by adding some fields and change name of other but when i inherited the related model which is 'account.analytic.line':
and add the 'analytic ' module in the manifest as depends

```
from odoo import models, fields, api

class mham_app(models.Model):

    _inherit='account.analytic.line'

    date_deadline = fields.Date('Deadline')
    is_done = fields.Boolean('Done?')
    active = fields.Boolean('Active?', default=True)
```

the follow is the **manifest**.py file

```
# any module necessary for this one to work correctly
'depends': ['analytic'],
```

the following is  full error massage

```
    2019-02-05 20:21:54,528 17339 ERROR New_todo odoo.modules.registry: Failed to load registry 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 60, in __new__
    return cls.registries[db_name]
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/tools/func.py", line 69, in wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/tools/lru.py", line 44, in __getitem__
    a = self.d[obj].me
KeyError: 'New_todo'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 86, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 455, in load_modules
    env['ir.model.data']._process_end(processed_modules)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_model.py", line 1624, in _process_end
    record.unlink()
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_model.py", line 637, in unlink
    self._prepare_update()
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_model.py", line 584, in _prepare_update
    model = self.env[rec.model]
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/api.py", line 820, in __getitem__
    return self.registry[model_name]._browse((), self)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 176, in __getitem__
    return self.models[model_name]
KeyError: 'mham_app.mham_app'
2019-02-05 20:21:54,532 17339 INFO New_todo werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [05/Feb/2019 20:21:54] "POST /longpolling/poll HTTP/1.1" 500 - 421 0.353 1.094
2019-02-05 20:21:54,541 17339 ERROR New_todo werkzeug: Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/msafi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 270, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/home/msafi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 258, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/service/server.py", line 350, in app
    return self.app(e, s)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 128, in application
    return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 117, in application_unproxied
    result = odoo.http.root(environ, start_response)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 1318, in __call__
    return self.dispatch(environ, start_response)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 1291, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)
  File "/home/msafi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 766, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 1469, in dispatch
    odoo.registry(db).check_signaling()
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/__init__.py", line 81, in registry
    return modules.registry.Registry(database_name)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 62, in __new__
    return cls.new(db_name)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 86, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 455, in load_modules
    env['ir.model.data']._process_end(processed_modules)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_model.py", line 1624, in _process_end
    record.unlink()
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_model.py", line 637, in unlink
    self._prepare_update()
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_model.py", line 584, in _prepare_update
    model = self.env[rec.model]
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/api.py", line 820, in __getitem__
    return self.registry[model_name]._browse((), self)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 176, in __getitem__
    return self.models[model_name]
KeyError: 'mham_app.mham_app' - - -
```

although of there is no model name mham_app.mham_app
And the error occure also comes if I change the name to something else

Comment: Is there any other code in your `mham_app` class?

Comment: Yes, i have added to the question.

Comment: Do you use `New_todo` somewhere else in your custom code?